# ListView with images in android

Tags: android

I am developing an android application.I have a list of items.I have a text.Below the list i have 2 buttons delete and reset.Can anyone yell how should i proceed?

Thanks in advance
Tushar

Comment: What do you want to implement and achieve? You do not have a concrete question...

Comment: What you want to display in listView?

Answer (score 0):

mh maybe you can be more specific with your question or look at this guide for custom entries in a list http://blog.app-solut.com/2011/03/using-custom-layouts-for-spinner-or-listview-entries-in-android/

Answer (score 0):

The question need to be more specific. I think you need a page with a list of items and 2 buttons. So the list items might be selectable in order to select and delete.

U need to go through how to set up a view in android. Here is the link to refer:
http://developer.android.com/resources/tutorials/views/index.html

The form stuff will be more suitable for u I guess ;)
http://developer.android.com/resources/tutorials/views/hello-formstuff.html